# Why my checkbox doesn't work in my Dialog?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I create a component for my Dialog and my Checkbox my issue is when my checkbox is not in the Dialog the update works but when it's inside it doesn't work. I don't understand why.

```
const Popup = ({ title, handleClose, opened, children }) => {
    return (
        <Dialog className='react-popup-template' fullWidth={true} maxWidth='sm' open={opened} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="parent-modal-title" aria-describedby="parent-modal-description">
            <DialogContent id="modal-description" >
                <div>
                    {title && <div><h4 style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize : '23px' }}>{title}</h4><br/></div>}
                    {children}
                </div>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
const CheckBox = (value, onChange) => {
    return (
        <label>
            <input type='checkbox' value={value} onChange={onChange} />
        </label>)
} 

const App = () =>{
    const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = React.useState(false)
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false)
    const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('')
    const [description, setDescription] = React.useState('')
    const showModal = (title) =>{
        setTitle(title)
        setDescription(<CheckBox value={checked} onChange={() => {setChecked(!checked)}} />)
    }
    return (
<button onClick={() => {showModal('Title')}}>showModal</button>
        <PopupTemplate title={title} handleClose={() => { setOpenPopup(false) }} opened={openPopup}>
                {description}
        </PopupTemplate>)
}
```

Comment: This is why it's not a good idea to not have jsx in state ... Also not clear tbh what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @KcH I'm trying to open a modal to validate my input to go to an other step but my issue is actually the state doesn't change so how can I do it ?

Comment: @KcH I try something else and it works thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `Checkbox` you should either destructure your props

```js
const CheckBox = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </label>
  );
};
```

Or use your props via the `props` value

```js
const CheckBox = (props) => {
  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} />
    </label>
  );
};
```

EDIT:

The state only updates the first time you click the checkbox. Using the callback in the `setChecked` method will solve this.

```js
...
setDescription(
  <CheckBox
    value={checked}
    onChange={() => {
      setChecked((prevChecked) => !prevChecked);
    }}
  />
);
...
```

PS: I don't now if its just a copy/paste error, but you're missing `setOpenPopup(true)` in your `showModal` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as mui uses forwarRef for its components this should work,

setDescription(<CheckBox checked={checked} onChange={e => setChecked(!checked)} />)